# Wordpress website menu visibility on login page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

As, when you are logging in on your Wordpress website, the main menu is not visible.  Is it possible to show the main menu on WordPress login page as when my customers are logging in, they should see the menu above the login fields for username/email and password.

Comment: This can be done, however this question does not provide enough information for the Stack Overflow community to help you. Please share a [mcve] and show us anything you have tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I tried a few plugins but didnt work. I also tried adding separate pages but the shorcodes I use in Bold Builder plugin for login forms destroys my all layout as it appears on top of my navigation menu.

Comment: It might require making some changes to your template